# jsp:include or c:import With Wildfly 9

Tags: jsp, jstl, wildfly

We are trying to migrate from JBoss 7 to Wildfly 9 and are having a very strange issue with any of our JSPs that contain a `<jsp:include>` or `<c:import>`.

The problem is hard to describe but what appears to be happening is that the page is repeated within itself infinitely.

Imagine standing in a hall of mirrors. When you look straight ahead you see the room repeated over and over into infinity, with each instance contained in the one before it. That is essentially what our pages look like within the include/import block when displayed in WF9.

The exact same code works fine in JBoss 7 (our current production environment) and also Wildfly 8. We didn't get migrated to Wildfly 8 soon enough so we're now trying to make the jump to Wildfly 9 (although I see that Wildfly 10 is now available; haven't tried it yet).

I don't see anything in the WF 9 release notes regarding these directives and was wondering if anyone has experienced this problem and how you may have solved it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the cause of this problem so I've decided to write our web pages (700+ of them) to not use `jsp:include` or `c:import`. Rather, we will use Javascript to dynamically build the necessary HTML that would be imported/included since Wildfly 9 cannot handle these entries. A ton of work I shouldn't have to do.